How to set consent properly in Firabse sdk for Unity?

I'm using Firebase analytics and crashlytics in Unity.
Anyone got an example of how to properly implement the consent flow?
If I'm using cmp (google ump), can I use it for firabase consent?
Tried to read google's documentation but only find old ios and android implementation and not Unity.

To clarify, what platform(s) are you building for? The instructions for iOS and Android stand for Unity as well and you just use the equivalent Unity methods.

I'm currently building for android only. My problem is that I didn't fully understands the android and ios instructions.

Please tell me which parts; I will help clarify point by point.

I updated the Consent Mode docs to reflect how to do this in Unity.
The primary catch is that to properly edit the manifest as described above, you must Override the Android App Manifest or Export an Android project and then build it from there.

Thank you very much. Maybe you can help me to understand the flow. I disable the analytics and only after the user accept my terms and conditions and cmp for eea users I can turn the analytics back on?

Bingo! As described in "Temporarily disable collection": "To re-enable collection, such as after an end-user provides consent, call the setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled() method of the FirebaseAnalytics"

As this page is referenced by Google searches and the implementation will soon be mandatory, I aim to save readers time.

Please add these lines to "Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml" (within the "application" section):

<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_default_allow_analytics_storage" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_default_allow_ad_storage" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_default_allow_ad_user_data" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_default_allow_ad_personalization_signals" android:value="true" />


This will help verify that everything is functioning correctly. Remember to enable verbose output in Logcat for detailed logging information.



    adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
    adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC


There should be line like: "Setting consent, ... AD_STORAGE=granted"

For those solely using personalization in ads, AdMob's consent form offers a convenient solution to enable or disable ad personalization.



    string purposeConsents = ApplicationPreferences.GetString("IABTCF_PurposeConsents");
    string status = (purposeConsents != "00000000000") ? "true" : "false";
    FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserProperty(FirebaseAnalytics.UserPropertyAllowAdPersonalizationSignals, status);


